# Left outer join Stored Procedure Error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, left-join

I got an error in this stored procedure.It execute successfully but when It call  within two parameters,I got this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'upper(t1.district_code)=t2.district_code)' at line 1

This is My Code :

```
 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_db.sp_temp_test;
 CREATE PROCEDURE test_db.`sp_temp_test`(in sdate DATE, edate DATE )
 begin
 DECLARE tbname VARCHAR(20);

 DECLARE y INT;
 DECLARE m INT;

 SET y = SUBSTRING(Year(sdate),3,2);  
 SET m = Month(sdate);
 SET tbname=''; 

 IF (10>m>0) THEN
 SET  tbname = CONCAT('post_0',m,y);
 ELSE
 SET  tbname = CONCAT('post_',m,y);
 END IF;



set @st = concat("select t1.*,t2.* ",
            " from (select a.event_source,b.Region,", 
            " a.cost as Value ,",
            "d.othre_names,d.sur_name, c.company_name,e.district_name",
            " from ", tbname," a, table_b b ,tabel_c c,test2db.District e",
             " where a.acc_no=d.acc_no",
            "  and a.event_date>='", sdate, "'  ",
            "  and a.event_date<='", edate, "'  ",
            "  and e.district_code=c.district_code",
            "  and a.event_type_id='11' ",      
            "  group by b.Region, a.event_type_id  ",
            "  order by  b.Region)t1  ",
            " left outer join testdb2.District t2",
            "on upper(t1.district_code)=t2.district_code");       

            prepare stmt from @st;
            execute stmt;
            deallocate prepare stmt;

            end;
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is your data sharded/partitioned like that? I think your `post_N` table should be consolidated into a single `post` table and let the underlying DBMS handle partitioning instead of implementing it in your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one space before on. for example
 " on upper(t1.district_code)=t2.district_code");

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a space before "on" in that last line. Your concatenation will not add word delimiters between your keywords. You are ending up with "...left outer join **t2on** upper..."

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of errors in your SQL statement. Here some

- the `group by` use only `b.Region` and `a.event_type_id`, but you have a lot more columns in your select. This isn't possible.
- the `order by` in an inner select is not useful, move to the most outer select.
- maybe there are some typing error like `othre_names` (instead of `other_names`)

Can you print your constructed sql statement and execute manually? You should get better error messages.